# ViewController from StoryBoard make ViewDidLoad called twice

Tags: ios, storyboard, segue, viewcontroller, viewdidload

I would like to make (from my StoryBoard) a ViewController that I will be able to push from anywhere by code (this ViewController will be used a lot of time, so I don't wan't to add tons of segues in the StoryBoard...).

I also have to pass some variables from the current ViewController to the pushed one.
To do it I'm using this code :

```
NBItemDetailsViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ItemDetailsViewController"];
vc.item = self.selectedItem;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

It nearly works, but in the pushed ViewController, the viewDidLoad method is called twice. The first time, I can get the item, but the second, it is null. Of course it seems like the displayed ViewController is the one of the second call, and I can't get my item.

Any idea ?
Is there a better option, using segues in the StoryBoard (I can't believe there is no way to reuse a ViewController in the StoryBoard...) ?

PS : I already tried to use viewDidAppear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might create a subclass of `UIViewController` (MyRegularViewController) and assign a .xib by (MyRegularViewController.xib)

`File > New > File > User Interface > Empty`

and drag a `UIViewController` to your emtpy xib file. Associate your MyRegularViewController with that xib, then customize it.

Now you can use it anywhere you want simply like this;

```
MyRegularViewController *regular = [[MyRegularViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyRegularViewController" bundle:nil];
self.navigationController pushViewController:regular animated:YES];
```

You are not obligated to use storyboard in all cases, in fact using your storyboard for something like this situation will mess your storyboard. Simply use a xib and a custom class for this.

Comment: Yes, that's what I will probably end with. I will accept your answer if I don't find another solution. Thanks

Comment: @Tim, This is no different than having an unconnected view controller in the storyboard. If viewDidLoad is being called twice, then you're doing something wrong. Do you have a segue attached to the NBItemDetailsViewController?

Comment: You got it ! I have a container view in the ViewController, if I remove it it works (but I need it ^^).

Comment: In fact the problem was not that the ViewController did contain a ContainerView, it was that I set this ContainerView's class as the same that the ViewController in order to access to its properties. This seems not possible.

Comment: why don't you add your containerview as a subview in your viewcontroller, as a property, and access its properties? You shouldn't assign your containerview's class to a UIViewController